# Read value from user via html ,php ,mysql

Tags: php, html, arrays

I should create a database table and for this thanks to php and html I get number of fields and fields name from the user.And I can not handle it I try to fill toKeep array but I can't do it.My goal is keep fields in toKeep and then create tables.

```
Please enter the number of fields
    <form name="getNumber" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="number" >
<input type="submit" name="field" id="field">
</form>
<?php
    $number=$_POST["number"];
    $num=(int)$number;
    $i=1;
    $toKeep = array();
    while ($i<=$num){
        echo "please enter fieldname";
        $fieldname = "field" . $i;
    ?>

<form name="X" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($fieldname);?>">
</form>

<?php
    $toKeep[i]=$_POST['$fieldname'];
    //echo $fieldname;
    echo $toKeep[i];
    $i=$i+1;
    }


    ?>
<form name="X" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="field" id="field">
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['field'])){
    echo $toKeep[0];
    echo $toKeep[1];
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? Any errors?

Comment: Actually don't give any errors but also don't fill the toKeep array.

Comment: One thing: don't use single quotes if you want to evaluate variables: `$_POST[$fieldname];`

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 typos there .
You need to change 
`$toKeep[i]=$_POST['$fieldname'];` 
to
 `$toKeep[$i]=$_POST[$fieldname];`